# magento-change product name base on value of custom attribute

Tags: product, checkout

I need to write some code in checkout/order review section. file--- app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\review/item.phtml

Now the problem in details:

I have a drop down custom attribute PURCHASE_TYPE. And one of its value MARGIN

Now, I need to show (*) after the product name in the checkout/order review which products custom attribute  PURCHASE_TYPE. is  MARGIN.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step1: `goto app\design\frontend\yourpackgae\default\template\checkout\onepage\review\item.phtml`

Step2: load product by **$item->getProductId();**

```
$ProductObject=Mage:getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())
```

Get product value from `$ProductObject->getAttributeText('purchase_type')`;

and the code

```
$this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) .''. $ProductObject->getAttributeText('purchase_type'
```

Comment: hi, Amit Bera, Thanks for your answer. but my problem is, i dont to add attribute text with product name. I just want to add (*) symbol.which products Purchase_type attributes value is "Margin". (*) is not products attribute or value.